# How to access vuejs component properties from using cypress?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

Hi I want to access vuejs component properties from using cypress because am not able to locate elements uniquely form html/css.
our application UI developed in Vuejs so i tried to access vue component form dom object with cypress
for ex on console, 
1.var a=document.querySelector('#action_items_list > div.fill-height.col > div > div > div.fill-height > div:nth-child(1)')

2.a.**vue**.props.kitItemId

now how i implement this thing in cypress to access the data for a component and get() will not take this as an argument coz it requried a DOM element to perform an action.

Comment: Can we access these vue component value by document object by cypress??

Comment: From my point of view the problem is that you try to access the component from the DOM (that does contain only the result of the rendering). If you have mounted the component beforehand and want to access the props you could use [vue-test-utils](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/props.html) (which is integrated in [cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/events-vue#Using-Vue-Test-Utils)). Like `let component=null;cy.mount(Component, {props: {whatever: ...}}).then((wrapper) => {component = wrapper;}); component.props().whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cy.get('#action_items_list > div.fill-height.col > div > div > div.fill-height > div:nth-child(1)')
    .then($item => {
        console.log($item[0].__vue__.kitItemId)
    })
```

Comment: Hi Not returning anything
is there any way to find these values of vue component by any other method of cypress
or by get() method??